# Retrieve data based on COUNT() and MONTH() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `users` and `likes` tables. A foreign key of the latter references id from `users` table. The task at hand is to retrieve all distinct users who have more than 100 likes in March 2018. I'm trying to extract date-related values from a column with a type `TIMESTAMP`

I've come up with only seeing that pretty much all of them have some likes in that period:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name 
FROM users AS u 
JOIN likes AS l ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE MONTH(l.timestamp) = 3 AND YEAR(l.timestamp) = 2018;
```

I guess I have to make use of `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` somehow, but all my struggles were leading to syntax errors. Please give a hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `select distinct`.  You want `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM users u JOIN
     likes l
     ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE MONTH(l.timestamp) = 3 AND YEAR(l.timestamp) = 2018
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100;
```

To be honest, it is better to write the `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE l.timestamp >= '2018-03-01' AND l.timestamp < '2018-04-01'
```

This allows the SQL engine to use an index on `timestamp`, if one is available.

Comment: `Having count(*) > 100` for the requirement `users who have more than 100 likes`

Comment: +10. or, `INSERT INTO likes (user_id,timestamp) VALUES ('Gordon Linoff',NOW()); COMMIT;`